# How can I intentionally create random floating point / decimal precision errors in java?

Tags: java, random, floating-point, double, precision

My goal is to generate random numbers that all have decimal precision errors.

Here are some examples of types of numbers I would like to generate:

```
1.8181818723678589
1.2727272510528564
0.444444477558136
```

Here are strategies I have tried.

`parseFloat("4.01500000000000000001");`
`BigDecimal.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat()).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat())).doubleValue();`

None of the things I tried have created even a single number similar to that which I am looking for.

Comment: So basically, you want the decimal places to be regular for a while, then becomes irregular?

Comment: @Sweeper I think that all these numbers have some sort of decimal point error. 

I found these numbers originally from testing different touch events such as Touch.radiusX Touch.radiusY. I want to learn how to mathematically create similar rounding errors to these events.

Comment: It sounds like you are using some sort of UI framework? If you can look into their source code, you should be able to see exactly how `radiusX` and `radiusY` is calculated. Anyway, in general, errors accumulate, so as long as you do enough calculations, you'll see them. Try adding one hundred 0.1s together (all `float`s), you get 10.000002. Is that the kind of error you want? Don't use `BigDecimal` because it represents things _exactly_ - the opposite of what you want.

Comment: @Sweeper I am getting these numbers from Chrome on mobile by pressing on my screen. I put a link to it below. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/radiusX

I will also check chromium source to see how this is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the exact values actually *meant* are:

- 1.81 repeating
- 1.27 repeating
- 0.4 repeating

Observe that in each number there are around 7 or 8 digits that are "correct", and around 18 digits in total. `float`s are usually precise to 7 to 8 digits, and `double`s are usually precise to around 18 digits, so I suspect that these numbers are actually `floats` (or 32-bit floating point numbers) that got "widened" to be `double`s

1.81 repeating is 20/11, so I tried:

```
float i = 20f/11f;
double d = i;
System.out.println(d);
```

This prints exactly the value you saw - 1.8181818723678589.

1.27 repeating is 14/11 and 0.4 repeating is 4/9. You can try both of these yourself. They all produce your desired numbers. This strongly suggests that the errors are produced by widening a `float` to 64 bits.